# Encrypt php project to prevent duplication

Tags: php, encryption

I have made a plugin for WordPress and I want to encrypt a few files in it to prevent code alteration. Say I want to encrypt `plugin-activator.php` file only but can it be executed without decrypting the file?

I came through Hashids, but I don't know if it would work without decrypting the script. Additionally, I am not looking to install any special PHP Library to achieve encryption.

Tell me if there is any other method to prevent alteration in code.

Comment: You cannot encrypt your PHP code without using an external encoder. However, you can obfuscate part of your PHP code which can be handled from any PHP environment.

Comment: How can I obfuscate and would can I prevent deobfuscate?

Comment: You cannot prevent deobfuscate.

Comment: Then there is no need to obfuscate either. This doesn't solve the problem.